# Why some JavaScript functions don't work when a anchor is activate (#anchor in URL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, scrollto

**EDIT NUMBER ONE : It is really strange in fact my javascript functions don't work when I click on the anchor ! Really... If someone has an idea I would be so thanksful** !

I am coding a simple home page composed of a header with forms and a section with an introduction to the content of my website.

And I have two problems because of my anchor (at least it seems) : it looks like my javascript functions don't work when I click on the anchor. I will explain you more precisely.

**I. Javascript function for displaying forms**

The first part is composed of a header. On this header you have a form to connect or register. I don't diplay the both forms : indeed I display first only the connection form. if the user is not a member he just need to click on "I don't have an account" and then my connection form is replaced by the register form. (thanks to a jquery code)

At the end of header I put an arrow. When you click on it you go directly to the presentation of the content of my website (thanks to an anchor).

**II. Javascript function for displaying a summary of precise content**

After having clicked on the anchor the users face to 3 circles (with title : content 1, content 2 and content 3). When the user flies over a circle, this circle moves into a rectangular form and display a summary of the content.

But when I don't click on the anchor : everything works fine. But when I click on the anchor the javascript functions for  displaying the forms and for displaying the content from the circle don't work at all ! I have no idea how to fix it. I try to erase the anchor from the url for instance : http://mywebsite/#anchor to http://mywebsite but I didn't manage so far.

**III. Codes**

Here are my HTML code and Javascript code.

```
<header>
        <div class="intro-header">
            <h1>TEST MY WEBSITE</h1>
            <div class="divForm_global">
                <div class="divForm_connexion" id="divForm_connexion">
                    <h3>Connect to your account</h3>
                    <form class="form_connexion">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address: </label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginemail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginpasswordd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="login">Submit</button>
                        <p id="one"><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>
                        <p id="two">Don't have account? <a class="signup" href="#" id="signup">Sign up here</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="divForm_register" id="divForm_register">
                    <h3>Register Form FOR TEST</h3>
                    <form class="form_register">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name/Pseudo: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address: </label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registeremail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerpassword">
                        </div>                          
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="register">Submit</button>
                        <p id="two">Already have an account? <a class="signin" href="#" id="signin">Sign in</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#service" class="btn btn-circle">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                </a>                
            </div>
            <hr class="intro-divider" />
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="service">
        <script src="js/display_content_circle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
            <h2>I CONTINUE TO TEST HERE </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="test>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 75px;">
                    <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 250px;">
                            <div class="panel circular-panel panelGeneral">
                                <h3 class="header" style="font-family:stencil,serif;color:red;">TITLE CIRCLE 1 TEST</h3>
                                <div class="description-header" style="display: none;">
                                    <i class="panel-icon flaticon-tool"></i><a href="#" style="color:red; font-style:bold;">TEST HERE</a>
                                </div>
                                <p class="description" style="display: none;">TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here you will find my javascript function to display the content of the circle when I fly over the circle :

```
var main = function()
    {
        $('.circular-panel').hover(function()
        {
            $(this).animate(
            {
                width: '250px',  
                height: '250px', 
                borderWidth: '1px', 
                borderRadius: '4px', 
                lineHeight: '24px'
            }, 100);
            $(this).children('.header').fadeOut(100);
            $(this).children('.description-header').fadeIn(100);
            $(this).children('.description').fadeIn(100);
        }, function()
        {
            $(this).animate(
            {
                width: '150px', 
                height: '150px', 
                borderWidth: '5px', 
                borderRadius: '50%', 
                lineHeight: '140px'
            }, 100);
            $(this).children('.header').fadeIn(100);
            $(this).children('.description-header').fadeOut(100);
            $(this).children('.description').fadeOut(100);
        });


        $('.extra').children('.glyphicon-remove').click(function()
        {
            $('.extra').slideUp('fast');
            $('.copyright').animate(
            {
                marginBottom: '0px'
            }, 'fast');
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(main);
```

In order not to overwhelm you with codes I decided not to show you my code for the function that changes the forms as I think if we manage to solve the problem with the "circle" I will manage to solve the problem for the forms I guess.But if you need it just ask me

I really think the problem comes from those functions as they use "$document"  and maybe this is modified because of the anchor. So the selector doesn't work as document is my website withtout anchor (http://Website) and when I click on the anchor I have (http://website/#anchor).

Do you have an idea ? Can we deactivate the anchor's URL ? (clicking on the anchor without that #anchor is added to the URL of the website ?)

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? Generally when something "doesn't work" after clicking something else it's because a called function has errors in it.

Comment: Found one error copying your html into jsfiddle.net `<div id="test>` missing closing double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

This would prevent the defaut behavior of links also tho.